# Loop through an array of objects, compare the ids and merge the object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6

I am looping through an array of objects and trying to get the id and carId of them. I am doing it this way:

```
getIds(array) {
        for (var index in array) {
            var combinedIds = array[index];
            if (!!combinedIds.id && !!combinedIds.carId) {
                console.log('car id', combinedIds.carId);
                console.log('id', combinedIds.id);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code does not return any data. However when I modify the if statement to only `!!combinedIds.id` or `!!combinedIds.cardId` , I get the values of those keys.
The array this method takes in looks like this:

```
[
    {
        message: 'hello',
        id: "22"    
    },
    {
        day: 'nine',
        carId: "22"    
    },
]
```

I am basically trying to compare the `id` and `carId` of these objects in the array and merge them if they match. The array above is just an example, the original array has multiple objects with two objects having the same id and carId but not in a single object. What am I doing wrong here? Been stuck with this since days and would really appreiciate any help. TIA

Expected output would be:

```
[
    {
        message: 'hello',
        id: "22",
        day: 'nine',
        carId: "22"    
    },
    {
      //other objects with the same id and carId merged as above
    },
]
```

Comment: Please provide a more clear example with objects containing the ``cardId`` and the expected output.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Your loop currently means that you are expecting the same object in the array to have both `id` and `carId`

Comment: I have edited the question with the expected output. Please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, build a map which maps each carId to a specific car details.

Then filter our all objects which do not have a `carId`, and for all of them, find the matching car from the above map created, and append that data to your object.

```js
const input = [
    {
        message: 'hello',
        id: "22"    
    },
    {
        day: 'nine',
        carId: "22"    
    },
];

const withCarIdObj = input.reduce((res, item) => {
  if (!item.carId) return res;

  res[item.carId] = item;
  return res;
}, {});

const merged = input.filter(item => !item.carId).map(item => {
  return {...item, ...(withCarIdObj[item.id] || {})}
});

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: You sir, have my massive respect! I have been stuck with this problem since forever and this is a genius solution. Thank you so much! @Ayush Gupta

Comment: what would be the time complexity for this? @Ayush Gupta I am guessing O(N) since we are iterating through n objects

Comment: this fails when another object in the array with a different carId/id is present. It returns only the merged object and ignores the other one @AyushGupta

Comment: @boomchickawawa what do you mean? Your original question doesn't mention anything about such inputs.

Comment: it is an edge case we have consider even though it is not mentioned. it would not make sense to not return the other objects in the array and return only the merged ones @AyushGupta

Comment: @boomchickawawa edge case is different than new inputs. What will happen if the objects do not have `id` and `carId`. Is that also an edge case?

Comment: @boomchickawawa you should always include special cases your data might have in the question. How would I know what you want to do in this case anyways? Return or filter it out is a choice based on requirements which warrants mentioning.

Comment: any idea how to handle when there are uneven objects with their ids matching and some of them not?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like:

```js
let array = [
  {
    message: 'hello',
    id: '22'
  },
  {
    day: 'nine',
    carId: '22'
  }
]

let newArray = array
  .filter(obj => !!obj.id)
  .map(obj => ({
    ...obj,
    ...array.filter(carIdObj => carIdObj.carId && carIdObj.carId == obj.id)[0]
  }))

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: This runs in O(n^2) though.

Comment: @AbdElbeltaji this would fail when a carId/id with different number is present in the array